# update query in Oracle procedure updated with wrong value

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle-xe

The below mentioned procedure is intended to:

1. fetch jobids from cp_work_card which exist in cpTemplateWorkCard
2. Fetch the first record of bhours for the jobid from the cp_work_card
3. update the same to cpTemplateworkCard

Hwoever, all the rows of cpTemplateworkCard are updated with the value of bHours found in last row. But, the values in the variable are stored correctly while execution

```
DECLARE
     jobId       VARCHAR2(30);
     bHours      float;
     idx         NUMBER(4,0);
     CURSOR         c1 
     IS
        select distinct 
               cp.job_id 
          from cp_work_card cp,
               cptemplateworkcard temp 
         where cp.job_id = temp.JOBID;
BEGIN
   idx:=1;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('id : jobId  :  bHours');
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO jobId;
      EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
      select cpw.BUDGET_HOUR 
        into bHours 
        from cp_work_card cpw 
       where cpw.job_id=jobId 
         AND rownum<2;
      /*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Budget Hours: '||bHours);

      UPDATE TO CPTEMPLATE*/

      UPDATE cptemplateworkcard tmpCard 
         SET tmpCard.BUDGET_HOUR=bHours 
       where tmpCard.JOBID=jobId;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(idx || ' : ' || jobId || ' : ' || bHours);
      idx:= idx+1;

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you achieve the same with a single SQL update statement?

```
UPDATE cptemplateworkcard tmpcard
   SET tmpcard.budget_hour = (SELECT budget_hour
                                FROM cp_work_card cp
                               WHERE cp.job_id = tmpcard.jobid
                                 AND rownum < 2)
 WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 
         FROM cp_work_card cp
        WHERE cp.job_id = tmpcard.jobid);
```

I haven't tested this but the principle is the same...

EDIT: Given your constraints and if you must use a procedure then could you not:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT
             cp.job_id,
             cp.budget_hour
        FROM cp_work_card cp
       INNER JOIN cptemplateworkcard temp
          ON (cp.job_id = temp.jobid)
       WHERE rownum < 2;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'job_id  :  budget_hour' );

   FOR c_rec IN c1
   LOOP
      UPDATE cptemplateworkcard tmpcard
         SET tmpcard.budget_hour = c_rec.budget_hour
       WHERE tmpcard.jobid = c_rec.job_id;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( c_rec.job_id || ' : ' || c_rec.budget_hour );
   END LOOP;
END;
```

EDIT:
**FYI, your current procedure isn't working because you have named your variable holding the job ID as `jobId` which also happens to be the name of a column in the table `cptemplateworkcard`. Therefore when you perform your update it defaults to thinking your `WHERE` clause is comparing the table column with itself thereby updating every row with whatever the value of `bHours` is. When the procedure has finished, obviously the last value of `bHours` what the final value returned from the cursor hence you are seeing all the values in the table set to this final value.**

If you rename your `jobId` variable to something like `v_jobid` then it should solve the problem.

Hope it helps...

If the only constraint is that it must be in a PL/SQL procedureal block then this will be the most efficient procedure:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE cptemplateworkcard tmpcard
      SET tmpcard.budget_hour = (SELECT budget_hour
                                   FROM cp_work_card cp
                                  WHERE cp.job_id = tmpcard.jobid
                                    AND rownum < 2)
    WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 
            FROM cp_work_card cp
           WHERE cp.job_id = tmpcard.jobid);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQL%rowcount||' record(s) updated');
END;
```

Comment: yes it can be done with simple query... procedure is part of objective.. anyways was ASKED to do!!!

Comment: OK, what are your constraints for writing the procedure? It MUST be a procedure is obviously one, do you have to use a simple LOOP, could it be a cursor FOR loop instead etc.? See edit..

Comment: didnt get c_rec . I am almost a novice in pl/sql. i jst want to iterate over the jobId list. Cursor is not must. Objective should be achieved with procedure. Thats the only constraint i have

Comment: Did you see my edit as to why your current syntax isn't working? You've named your local variable jobId the same as a column in the table cptemplateworkcard. Rename your variable and your procedure will work.

Answer (score 0):

IF your statements/conditions are all correct then executing the following statement instead of your stored procedure should do exactly what you want:

```
UPDATE cptemplateworkcard tc 
SET tc.BUDGET_HOUR=(SELECT cpw.BUDGET_HOUR FROM cp_work_card cpw where cpw.job_id=tc.JOBID AND rownum<2)
WHERE tc.JOBID IN (select cp.job_id from cp_work_card cp);
```